# Rotate list by the input number

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

when I try to input the function below. I come up with how to rotate the func when the input is positive, however, when it is negative, I don't how to solve it. The code is below:

```
-- rotate : Takes a list, and a value, and rotates the list around
-- by the number of elements indicated
rotate :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
rotate ls m = case ls of 
    [] -> [] 
    x:xs 
       | m == 0 -> x:xs
       | otherwise -> rotate (xs ++ [x]) (m-1)
```

Comment: What did you try, what is not working?

Comment: Taking an element from the front of the list is easy, but putting it on the back is hard. Taking an element from the back is hard, but putting it back in in the front is easy.

Comment: Hint: rotating *n* places to the left, is the same as rotating *m-n* places to the right with *m* the length of the list to rotate.

Comment: I figure it out! Thank you guys very much!

Comment: If you want to rotate more than 1 position at the time, how about using [`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a],[a])`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/splitAt_f.html)?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this is by seeing a rotation of *m* places to the left as a rotation of *m* mod *n* items to the right, with *n* the length of the list to rotate.

We thus can implement this as:

```
rotate :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
rotate xs m
  | m < 0 = rotate xs (m `mod` length xs)
rotate ls m = case ls of 
    [] -> [] 
    x:xs 
       | m == 0 -> x:xs
       | otherwise -> rotate (xs ++ [x]) (m-1)
```

It might also be better to look for a way to rotate more efficiently than rotating one position at a time.